# Hidden select multiple items Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I've got several forms in my django app that require support for attachments.  Each form instance may have any number of attachments, including none.  I want to present a jQuery based upload widget for managing these uploads, allowing the uploads to be processed asynchronously.  The attachments are stored in their own model, so there is then a many-to-many from the attachments model to each model that requires attachments.  When an attachment is sucessfully uploaded and processed, the view handling the upload will return the id in the attachments model, which will then be inserted into a hidden field on the form.  I'm currently trying to decide how best to represent this in the form.

One method would be to simply have a single hidden input which takes a comma separated list of ids.  This would then require quite a lot of manual processing and validation on submission, which I can't help feeling could be avoided.

Elsewhere, I've used a HiddenInput for a single value where I'm doing something similar and dynamically adding items to the related model in the form.  I can't however see how I can extend this directly to a Many to Many from a simple Foreign Key.

Anyone able to suggest the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `formsets` or `model_formsets` to create a form for creating/editing multiple objects, also you can use `javascript` to add forms dynamically in your browser.

Comment: I don't think a formset is going to help here, my problem is not adding the upload form but passing the data returned by that back into the original form.

Comment: Nothing forbids you from using the data obtained using a form, modelform, modelformset, formset in your way. read the forms/modelforms documentation. what have you tried? Attaching your current code to the question may be more useful.